# Como guardar vários valores lidos para serem usados depois

Tags: python

Problema:

> "Leia uma sequência de 1000 inteiros. Leia outro inteiro N, e seu programa deve imprimir quantas vezes o inteiro N aparece nos 1000 anteriores. O programa para quando o primeiro inteiro dos 1000 for igual a -1. Para cada pacote de 1000 inteiros, deverá ser imprimida a seguinte frase: N appeared K times"

```
aux = 0
while aux < 1000
      aux = aux + 1
      a = input()
n = input()
```

Como eu encaixo o comando `for` e como eu guardo os valores de `a` para comparar entre si depois? Quero resolver dessa maneira porque sempre tenho dúvida nisso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guarde os números em uma [lista](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list):

```
numeros = [] # lista que vai guardar os números
for i in range(1000):
    n = int(input())
    if i == 0 and n == -1: # se o primeiro é -1, sai do loop
        break
    numeros.append(n) # adicionar o número na lista
```

Usei [`range(1000)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range), que gera a sequência de números entre 0 e 999 (ou seja, o `for` vai iterar 1000 vezes). E incluí a regra de parar quando o primeiro número for -1 (`break` interrompe o *loop*). E se isso ocorrer, a lista de números será vazia.

Também usei [`int`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int) para transformar o que foi digitado em número (vai dar erro se não for digitado um número, não está claro se é requisito do problema).

Já para contar quantas vezes `n` ocorre na lista:

```
if numeros: # se a lista não está vazia
    n = int(input())
    cont = 0
    for i in numeros:
        if i == n:
            cont += 1
    print(f'{n} appeared {cont} times')
```

Entendo que por ser um exercício, provavelmente querem que você faça a contagem manualmente, como está acima. Mas em todo caso, já existe isso pronto na linguagem, através do método `count`:

```
if numeros: # se a lista não está vazia
    n = int(input())
    print(f'{n} appeared {numeros.count(n)} times')
```

---

Outra opção para sair do programa (já que o enunciado diz que o programa deve parar) é usar [`sys.exit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.exit):

```
import sys
numeros = []
for i in range(1000):
    n = int(input())
    if i == 0 and n == -1: # se o primeiro é -1, para o programa
        sys.exit(0)
    numeros.append(n)

# não preciso mais verificar se a lista é vazia
n = int(input())
# etc...
```

Como `sys.exit` sai do programa, eu não preciso mais verificar se a lista é vazia depois do `for`.

---

E claro que também pode ser feito com `while` em vez de `for`:

```
i = 0
numeros = []
while i < 1000:
    n = int(input())
    if i == 0 and n == -1: # se o primeiro é -1, para o programa
        break # ou sys.exit(0)
    numeros.append(n)
    i += 1
```

---

E se a ideia é repetir várias vezes a leitura dos 1000 números, coloque tudo dentro de um *loop* infinito:

```
import sys
while True:
    numeros = []
    for i in range(1000):
        n = int(input())
        if i == 0 and n == -1: # se o primeiro é -1, para o programa
            sys.exit(0)
        numeros.append(n)

    n = int(input())
    cont = 0
    for i in numeros:
        if i == n:
            cont += 1
    print(f'{n} appeared {cont} times')
```

O `while True` se repete até que o `sys.exit` seja chamado.

Comment: Obrigada pela explicação! A minha maneira de usar o comando while não funcionaria, né? Precisa usar o ''for''.

Comment: @Maria Também dá pra fazer com `while`, atualizei a resposta adicionando essa opção.

Comment: Muito obrigada mesmo! Entendi perfeitamente!

Comment: Só uma observação: o programa entra com 1000 números várias vezes, até que, em uma dessas entradas, o primeiro seja -1.

Comment: @Maria Atualizei a resposta

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar um array para guardar os valores.

```
numeros = [] #cria o array
numeros.append(i) #add i ao array
```